Complexity Analysis for Computing the Square of a Graph
My friend and I were trying to do a CLRS problem but we're confused about the answer, more specifically the time complexity of the best algorithm:
QUESTION:
The 2-path of a directed graph G = (V, E) is the graph G^2 = (V, E^2) that provides an edge between nodes (u, v) if and only if the original graph G contains a path with at most two edges between u and v. Propose an efficient algorithm for computing G^2 from G given an Adjacency List.
MY APPROACH:
The algorithm was a simple brute force algorithm (I can't think of anything else, simply adding the edges will take these many steps at least). Iterate over all nodes, and all their edges and for each neighbor add all of their neighbors to the adjacency list of the node in question. Repeat for all nodes.
I know that the runtime is T = V + E + sum of (in degrees * out degrees) across all vectors. I just don't know how to characterize the complexity of the last term. I know this is right because each node n's neighbors are visited when considering the direct neighbors of n and when node n itself is being considered as an immediate neighbor (which can be measured by the in degree) and all of the out degree nodes will be added to the corresponding adjacency list each time. So the runtime is (in degree + 1) * out degree summed over all nodes. This can be simplified as follows:
SUM over nodes (in(v) + 1) * out(v)
SUM in(v) * out(v) + out(v)
SUM in(v) * out(v) + SUM out(v)
SUM in(v) * out(v) + E (since SUM in(v) = SUM out(v) = E for any graph)

So the total complexity V + E + SUM in(v) * out(v).
Is there anyway to simplify the last term?
Unable to quantify it, I took a different approach and got O(VE + V) ~ O(VE) which involved adding an node to the adjacency list of the transpose of the source node. ChatGPT is insistent on it being O(V+E) but refuses to highlight why.

could you clarify the output? do you want an adjacency list or a matrix representation?

adjacency list @SiminSimin

You are correct if the matrix representation is limited to adjacency list, this takes O(EV) time, scan through the adjacency lists takes O(E) time and keep a hash table for reachable vertex so for each edge u->v we check for v's adjacency list, taking O(V) time, adding new terms.
Note if the matrix can be converted to & from adjacency matrix this takes O(matmul) time where matmul is roughly |V|^2.3 in theory (thanks to fast matrix multiplication algorithms).
Note also if the graph is sparse i.e. |E|=O(V), then you might have something like O(V) time and O(n) space using the hash table method, because each vertex is visited degree(vertex) times.
